# Generate multiple binary files on ISE with different serial number

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I want to version all the boards on which I put a version of my FPGA. 
Each board shall have a different serial number stored in an internal ROM. It's basically a 10 digits number (ie: 0123456789).

After generating the binary file , how can I modify it to increment the number without damaging the FPGA and its behavior?

Have anyone already done this before?

Comment: It would be possible to do something like this with an internal Block RAM and the data2mem tool provided by Xilinx. You would be wasting one whole BRAM for 10 digits, but this might be the easiest way to accomplish what you are asking for. Google Xilinx user guide UG658.

Comment: I've got some spare memory in my design so that shouldn't be a problem. Thank you for your answer, I'll check data2mem.

Comment: "After generating the binary file , how can I modify it " you cannot. Therefore you need to find another way. Many FPGAs already have a unique serial number, so maybe you should reverse this idea, and use that number in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Which FPGA are you using? For Xilinx Devices you can use the USR_ACCESS register that can be set when creating the bitstream file. Limited up to 32bits of data.
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp497_usr_access.pdf

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I'm using a Spartan 6 FPGA which has no USR_ACCESS register.